# Plotting line segments from the set of startpoints and endpoints

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Suppose you have an array `a` with shape `(n,2,2)` which consists of coordinates of startpoints and endpoints of `n` line segmenets. How should one plot these line segments. My code doesn't work although it works element by element but not all of it at once. Here is my code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a=np.asarray([[[0,0],[1,1]],[[1,2],[2,3]],[[5,2],[2,6]],[[7,3],[5,9]]])
plt.plot(a[:,:,0],a[:,:,1])
plt.show()
```

What I want to get is this:
[image]
However my codes output is:
[image]
How should I correct this?

Comment: Also look into `LineCollection` http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick seems to be transposing, though I don't understand why this is the way it is!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
a=np.asarray([[[0,0],[1,1]],[[1,2],[2,3]],[[5,2],[2,6]],[[7,3],[5,9]]])
X=a[:,:,0].T
Y=a[:,:,1].T
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

You just have to transpose your arrays:

```
plt.plot(a[:,:,0].T,a[:,:,1].T)
```

The reason is `matplotlib`s standard interpretation of the axes of a 2D array `a`, where `a[i,j]` is meant to be the `i`-th value of the `j`-th plot.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is the following:

```
for aa in a:
    plt.plot(aa[:,0], aa[:,1])
```

Comment: For is pretty costly for large number of line segments.